# How many ways are there to prepare one of 400 varieties of coffee in one of 7 ways?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm hoping someone can check my thinking: I have 400 distinct varieties of coffee. Each can be prepared in 7 ways (black, cream and sugar, etc.). How many possible combinations are there? I'm thinking this is just ${n \choose k}$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you're mistaken. Here's a warmup: you have two types of coffee. Each can be prepared in three ways. How many combos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you wanted to list out all of the combinations. You want to make sure that you don't leave anything out, so you decide to do it in a systematic way by alphabetizing the type of coffee and the methods of preparation. Then you start listing:

- Aardvark Coffee, black
- Aardvark Coffee, cream only
- ... (4 more ways, and then) ...
- Aardvark Coffee, sugar only
- Alligator Coffee, black
- Alligator Coffee, cream only
- ...

After listing things out for a while, you realize that each type of coffee (Aardvark, Alligator, etc) gives you 7 entries on your list. Since you have 400 varieties of coffee, you have 400 groups of 7, so 2800 total entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of the $400$ varieties of coffee, and then independent from that you choose one of $7$ ways to prepare it. Hence the total number is $7 \times 400 = 2800$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are mistaken.Here you are not choosing n and k.It is like each variety of coffee (400) multiplied by 7 as all varieties of coffee are included.Combinations are not involved here in this case.

So your answer will be 2800.

Answer (score 0):

Every variety of coffee has 7 possible combinations, so there are 7 possible combinations per variety. There are 400 varieties, for a grand total of 7*400=2800 possible combinations.